# Simple rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm  new to RoR. I'm trying to create a basic web app where a Profile page shows a list of Items, which belongs to a specific profile.

So far I have:

```
rails generate scaffold Profile name:string
rails generate scaffold Item description:string
rake db:migrate
```

In the profile model: `has_many :items` In the item model: `belongs_to :profile`

When I try to create a new profile, I get the error:

```
undefined method `item' for #<Profile
```

Profile controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = profile.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @profiles }
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
    @profile = profile.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @profile }
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  # GET /profiles/new.json
  def new
    @profile = profile.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @profile }
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
    @profile = profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    @profile = profile.new(params[:profile])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @profile, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /profiles/1
  # PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    @profile = profile.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile = profile.find(params[:id])
    @profile.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Profile index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing profiles</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= profile.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', profile %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_profile_path(profile) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', profile, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New profile', new_profile_path %>
```

Profile _show.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :item %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Full error trace:

```
activemodel (3.2.12) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1161:in `value_before_type_cast'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1149:in `value_before_type_cast'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1043:in `block in to_input_field_tag'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1043:in `fetch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1043:in `to_input_field_tag'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:692:in `text_field'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1284:in `text_field'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/inputs/string_input.rb:13:in `input'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:29:in `block in render'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:27:in `each'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:27:in `render'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:29:in `block in render'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:27:in `each'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:27:in `render'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/wrappers/root.rb:15:in `render'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:117:in `input'
app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_profiles__form_html_erb___911765346923063960_2183588380'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `block in capture'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:187:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `capture'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:607:in `fields_for'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:378:in `form_for'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:29:in `block in simple_form_for'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:48:in `with_simple_form_field_error_proc'
simple_form (2.1.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:28:in `simple_form_for'
app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_profiles__form_html_erb___911765346923063960_2183588380'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/profiles/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_profiles_new_html_erb___3444063506780261827_2182112400'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:29:in `new'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__312850119216024862__process_action__607287929354052739__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1382692569756144731__call__1219384665416315194__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: what does you new, create action look like?

Comment: You don't have a create action. Please take a look at my answer and see if that helps you understand. Also, provide the code for your index.html view for your profile or the complete stack trace of the error. It seems you are calling profile.item somewhere.

Comment: index.html and _show.html provided above

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if you provided the full error stack trace or at least where it says the line number where the `item` is being called. The index and show didn't really provide what I was looking for

Comment: Added. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for this line `undefined method 'item' for #<Profile` that you didn't put in completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `has_many :items` to work you will need to have a `profile_id:integer` in your `Item` model.

You can accomplish by doing the following command

```
rails g migration add_profile_id_to_items profile_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

That should create the foreign key needed for the association.

After that you should be able to do things like this

```
@profile = Profile.create name: "MyProfile"
@item = @profile.items.build description: "This is my awesome item"
@item.save
```

There are different ways to create items for a profile but that's the most straight forward way. Then to retrieve those items you would do something like this

```
@profile = Profile.find(some_id)
@items = Item.where(profile_id: @profile.id).all
```

or

```
@profile = Profile.find(some_id)
@items = @profile.items
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Profile object does not have 'item' field.
Check your object's attributes by executing these commands:

```
rails console
Profile.connection
Profile
```

or visit your `db/schema.rb` file

You will see that there is no attribute :item in your object's hash.

You probably want to show the profile's items in your `show.html.erb` view. First though, you need to create an `Item` of the profile that it belongs to like so:

```
item = Item.new(description: "Test description", profile_id: 1)
```

Then you can do:

```
Profile.first.items
```

Second, you have an error in your controller. Object's class should be capitalized, so:

```
rails console
profile = profile.new(name: "Test profile")
```

will raise an error

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```